# jQuery UI modal dialog overlay fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, overlay, modal-dialog

Is it possible to apply a fade out effect on the jQuery UI modal dialog box overlay? The issue is that the overlay div is destroyed when the modal dialog box is closed preventing any kind of animation. This is the code I have that would work if the overlay div was not destroyed on close.

```
$("#edit-dialog-box").dialog(
{
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: "30em",
    show: "fade",
    hide: "fade",
    open: function()
    {
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").hide().fadeIn();
    },
    close: function()
    {
        $(".ui-widget-overlay").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Does fading out in `beforeclose` work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/276Ft/2/

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,

    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',

    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',

    open: function () {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay', this).hide().fadeIn();

        $('.ui-icon-closethick').bind('click.close', function () {
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut(function () {
              $('.ui-icon-closethick').unbind('click.close');
              $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
            });

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

​

Comment: I forked your fiddler to give the overlay a background color and the overlay still does not fade out. I also tried on my website with no luck.

Edit: Correct fiddler fork: http://jsfiddle.net/276Ft/

Comment: That's quite amazing and close enough to perfect for me! Update your answer above and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you very much!

Comment: @speranksy, thanks a ton! Things are working out nicely. I had some spare time so I did some snooping through the jQuery UI source code and created a hacky way of accomplishing this. This new way is a hack and it requires to make your own overlay (using jQuery UI of course). The two differences are that this new version will play both animations at the same time so the overlay disappears at the same time the dialog box does. This also handles the case that the dialog box can be closed in any way instead of just clicking the close button. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TtTrN/

Answer (score 1):

I advise not to bind the fadeOut of the overlay to the “closethick” close event.
This solution will work in all cases, for example if you use a “Cancel” button, or if the dialog closes itself after doing anything else due to other buttons:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    modal: true,

    width: '100px',
    height: '100px',

    show: 'fade',
    hide: 'fade',

    open: function () {
        $('.ui-widget-overlay', this).hide().fadeIn();
    },

    beforeClose: function(event, ui){
        // Wait for the overlay to be faded out to try to close it again
        if($('.ui-widget-overlay').is(":visible")){
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').fadeOut(function(){
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').hide();
                $('.ui-icon-closethick').trigger('click');
            });
            return false; // Avoid closing
        }
    }
});
```